# Ignite transactional cache with Spring transaction management

Tags: spring, caching, spring-transactions, ignite

I am exploring Ignite transactional cache. I already have a piece of code which uses Spring transaction management for JDBC. I wanted to integrate ignite transactional cache in the code using Spring cache abstraction.

I came across SpringTransactionManager (provided by Ignite) but I am unable to find the proper way to use it. Essentially, I want to do something like:

```
@Transactional
@Cacheable(cacheNames="personcache", key="#person.id", unless="#result == null")
public Person create(Person person) {
    String queryPerson = "insert into Person (id, name) values (?,?)";
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    jdbcTemplate.update(queryPerson, new Object[] { person.getId(), person.getName() });
    System.out.println("Inserted into Person Table Successfully");
    return person;
}
```

When the transaction commits, database and cache should get committed together. For this, Ignite docs mention the use of SpringTransactionManager https://www.gridgain.com/sdk/pe/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/transactions/spring/SpringTransactionManager.html.

I am not sure how to plug this transaction manager along with Spring's DriverManagerDataSource https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html

Can someone please guide me? An example would help a lot.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you provide `SpringTransactionManager` to Spring, it will create an Ignite transaction around the method annotated with `@Transactional`. First of all, I believe DB transaction will not be even started in this case. And even if it does, it will be independent from Ignite's one.

I see two options to solve this:

1. Configure Ignite with JTA [1] and use `JtaTransactionManager` that will be also aware of DB transactions.
2. Instead of `@Cacheable`, use integrate Ignite with DB via `CacheStore` [2][3] and use write-through. In this case Ignite will take care of transactional consistency.

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/transactions#integration-with-jta

[2] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/3rd-party-store

[3] https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/store/spring/CacheSpringStoreExample.java